# how to emulate \message in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, console

How do I emulate the `\message` primitive in Lua code in LuaTeX? I want something like `texio.write('foobarbaz')`, but without the line break within the word `foobarbaz`.

Example with lualatex:

```
\typeout{1}
\message{hellofoobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\typeout{2}
\message{hello}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\csname @@end\endcsname
```

I get this output on the console:

```
1
hellofoobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz
foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz
2
hellofoobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz fooba
rbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz fooba
rbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz )
```

The line is broken between `fooba` and `rbaz`. I want the line break before `fooba' instead.

Comment: texio.write('foobarbaz') would not normally put a linebreak within the word, tex wraps the output at a certain width if that is what you mean? But you posted no example?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Added an example which clarifies what I get and what I want.

Comment: is `\directlua{tex.print('\string\\message{foobarbaz }') tex.print('\string\\message{foobarbaz }')}` cheating?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: My production Lua code is slow, I want to display progress updates. Using `tex.print` all the progress updates would be delayed after my Lua code finishes. So in this use case it's cheating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to access the `\message` primitive from Lua.  If you want to write to the log you can use the `texio` library as suggested in David's answer, or if you just want to write to the terminal, `print` will actually do fine.

You can however, use asynchronous communication between Lua and TeX using coroutines, as recently shown in

> H. Hagen. Executing TeX in Lua: Coroutines. *TUGboat*, 39(1):41–43, 2018. https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121hagen-exec.pdf

Here is some sample code which will sleep for 1 second and then print “Hello” and a counter to the terminal.  This needs at least version 1.08.0 of LuaTeX for `texio.closeinput()`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
local stepper = nil
local stack = {}
local fid = 0xFFFFFF
local goback = "\\luafunction" .. fid .. "\\relax"

function tex.resume()
    if coroutine.status(stepper) == "dead" then
        stepper = table.remove(stack)
    end
    if stepper then
        coroutine.resume(stepper)
    end
end

lua.get_functions_table()[fid] = tex.resume

function tex.yield()
    tex.sprint(goback)
    coroutine.yield()
    texio.closeinput()
end

function tex.routine(f)
    table.insert(stack, stepper)
    stepper = coroutine.create(f)
    tex.sprint(goback)
end
```

```
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
tex.routine(function()
        for i = 1, 10 do
            -- some long task
            os.sleep(1) -- sleep 1 second instead
            tex.sprint("\\message{Hello " .. i .. "!}")
            tex.yield()
        end
end)
```

```
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

```
\typeout{1}
\message{hellofoobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\message{foobarbaz} \message{foobarbaz}
\typeout{2}
\message{hello}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{texio.write('foobarbaz ') texio.write('foobarbaz ')}


\typeout{3}
\directlua{
col=0
function zz(s)
local l=string.len(s)
if(col+l > 75) then
col=0
io.write('\string\n')
end
io.write(s)
col=col+l
end
}
\directlua{zz('hello')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}
\directlua{zz('foobarbaz ') zz('foobarbaz ')}


\csname @@end\endcsname
```

managing the columns and linebreaking yourself (which does mean that you have to start the first one at a forced newline) it produces

```
1
hellofoobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz
foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz
2
hellofoobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foob
arbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foo
barbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz 
3
hellofoobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz 
foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz 
foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz foobarbaz
```

Comment: zz invading lua now ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll get you a UK keyboard so you can find z.

Comment: does not work if string has >75 chars (untested)

Comment: @jfbu define "work": the spec was not to linebreak the supplied string, if you put in a string longer than that then it does what it does, Clearly it must be user error not a bug in the supplied code:-)

Comment: it will only "work" at `zzz` stage, i.e. do the linebreak appropriately even for long strings