# How to Set Lengths (Glue/Skips?, not Dimensions), in LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, nodes, lengths, lua, registers

I am trying to define a length, (not a dimension)—using Lua. But, I am having trouble with the syntax.  I think I am supposed to be using the same structures/prototypes as `glue_spec` in order to still be able to use standard LaTeX `length` macros on those new lengths.

**Question 1:** What is the way to define and set new lengths with just Lua?

**Question 2:** Is it correct that all "lengths" in LaTeX are Skip Nodes / Glue Nodes, and not Dimensions—and can be used with all of the standard `length` macros? (`\addtolength`, `\setlength`, etc.)

From the LuaTeX documentation:

```
tex.setskip (["global",] <number> n, <node> s)
tex.setskip (["global",] <string> s, <node> s)
<node> s = tex.getskip (<number> n)
<node> s = tex.getskip (<string> s)
```

The best I have been able to interpret everything I have read is:

```
local name = "MyLength";

local newLengthCommand =
    "\\newlength{\\" .. name .. "}";

% *** Actually Creates a New Length ...
tex.sprint(newLengthCommand);

local setLengthCommand =
    "\\setlength{\\" .. name .. "}{1in}";

% ***** Doesn't actually execute and set length ... why?
tex.sprint(setLengthCommand);

% ***** Debug to be sure syntax was right ...
-- tex.sprint("\\par\\verb|" .. newLengthCommand .. "|");
-- tex.sprint("\\verb|" .. setLengthCommand .. "|");

% **** Many Fails trying to hack registers ...
local gluespec = node.new(node.id("glue_spec"));
gluespec.width = tex.sp("1in");
tex.skip[name] = gluespec;

-- tex.setskip("global", name, gluespec);
-- tex.skip[name].width = value .. "in";
-- etc., etc..
```

Comment: Lua and TeX run asynchronously, so everything that you print in `tex.sprint` will only be seen *after* the Lua chunk has been processed.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Is there any way to decouple the "chunk"?   Like, could I include a .tex file inside another ... Just wondering if there is some chunk-erific magic I could do where I defined the lengths in one chunk, and set them in another.  Could I just `\directlua` two different files, synchronously, and it magically work?   (If I separated out the `\newlength`s from the `\setlength`s?)

Comment: it isn't clear what you want to do, do you want to set the lengths  using Lua or do you want to set them using TeX but write the tex from Lua (you can do either) also do you need to allocate a length register and give it a tex name (like `\newlength`) which you can also do from Lua but that is rather different thing.

Comment: for question 1 any lengths defined with `\newlength` are skip registers although other things that latex calls lengths and that may be set with `\setlength` are dimen registers eg `\textwidth`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Okay, I updated the question—hoping to clarify that I do, indeed, want to define and set the lengths using Lua syntax—preferably without having to resort to a `tex.sprint` or some such thing.  Are you saying that I could just use a `\gdef` to define a length and it will work just like a length, like: `token.set_macro("MyLength", "2in", "global")`.  And, are you saying that `Skip Registers` are just wrappers around `Dimension Registers`?

Comment: I didn't  mention gdef, but it depends what you mean by "work like a length" if you use `\newcommand\mylength{2in}` then you can use it in any context that a length can be used except you can not assign to it via `\setlength` you would nee `\renewcommand`. so you could use a macro from lua, or you could access a skip register, what do you plan to do with the length, why do you need a register?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following shows the skip register `\zzz` being set to a stretchy value from Lua.

It produces a log of

```
  \zzz has value 5.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt
```

lualatex document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\zzz


\directlua{
local sp=65536
tex.setglue("zzz", 5*sp, 1*sp,2*sp,0,0)
}

\typeout{\zzz has value \the\zzz}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

and a more complete example allocating lengths in tex and lua

```
\documentclass{article}

% a latex length 
\newlength\zzz
\setlength\zzz{123pt}
\typeout{\zzz is \meaning\zzz, \the\zzz} % happens to be skip register 43

\directlua{
local sp=65536
%
print ('skip alloc: ' .. tex.getcount(12)) % also 43 here
%
tex.setcount("global",12,tex.getcount(12)+1) % allocate
local myskipa=tex.getcount(12)
tex.setglue(myskipa, 5*sp, 1*sp,2*sp,0,0)
token.set_char("mylengtha", myskipa)
%
tex.setcount("global",12,tex.getcount(12)+1) % allocate
local myskipb=tex.getcount(12)
tex.setglue(myskipb, 5*sp, 1*sp,2*sp,2,3)% fil fill % expected 1,2??
token.set_char("mylengthb", myskipb)
}


% Lua allocated lengths, visible from TeX
\typeout{\skip\mylengtha is \skip\the\mylengtha, \the\skip\mylengtha}
\typeout{\skip\mylengthb is \skip\the\mylengthb, \the\skip\mylengthb}


% tex allocation picks up at 46,
% leaving 44 and 45 which wheer allocated in Lua
\newlength\zzzb
\setlength\zzzb{567pt}
\typeout{\zzzb is \meaning\zzzb, \the\zzzb} 

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

this produces

```
\zzz is \skip43, 123.0pt
skip alloc: 43
\skip \mylengtha is \skip 44, 5.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt
\skip \mylengthb is \skip 45, 5.0pt plus 1.0fil minus 2.0fill
\zzzb is \skip46, 567.0pt
```

Note I would have expected the stretch and shrink orders 2 and 3 to be fill and filll but they are coming out one less, I'll raise that on luatex list I think.  **confirmed** that luatex is incompatible with etex/ptex/pdftex/xetex here and uses 2,3,4 not 1,2,3 for fil, fill and filll glue stretch orders.

Comment: @elikakohen do you need a tex csname for the length? You could just use 2000 instead of 'zzz'

Comment: @elikakohen allocating a tex csname to a count register from lua is tricky, by far the easiest way is to do `tex.sprint(\\newlength\\zzz}`

Comment: @elikakohen If you really want to execute TeX code from within Lua immediately rather than delayed, you can use the coroutine technique presented by Hans Hagen in this TUGboat article http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121hagen-exec.pdf and applied by me in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470621/how-to-emulate-message-in-luatex/470667#470667

Comment: @elikakohen it isn't clear what else you need apart from this answer, you don't really need to allocate anything, all the skip registers exist all the time so you instead of the tex-declared `zzz` here you can simply use `tex.setglue(200, 5*sp, 1*sp,2*sp,0,0)  tex.setglue(201, 50*sp, 1*sp,2*sp,0,0) ...`  with numbered registers 200 and 2001 in this example. The first free skip register number is available in `\count12` (`tex.getcount(12)`)

Comment: as I say `\newlength` is not required at all, all it does is increase count12 by 1 so you know which is the next unused skip register, so if count12 is (say) 157 you can use `tex.setglue` starting at 158 with no clashes with tex allocated lengths. @elikakohen

Comment: @elikakohen extended example added