# luatex / tex without tex / parse math

Tags: math-mode, luatex

Inspired by the article [TeX without TeX](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX) on the LuaTeX wiki, I am curious if I can replicate the whole LaTeX parsing-to-rendering pipeline in a lua script.

I am currently stuck with math -- the `mknodes` function in the article (as well as a more advanced version I found [here](https://github.com/speedata/publisher/blob/ab4db4d91ed70bd6f041e1c4830e57fec72352d3/src/lua/publisher.lua#L2736)) just processes the characters indicating math-mode ($ symbols) as characters and does not construct math nodes.

Is there a way in LuaTeX to call TeX's built-in parsing for a piece of text? Preferably including math, macros, images, tables, larger glue after a period, etc. I am looking for a function that takes a paragraph of tex source code and returns a node list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your requests seem slightly contradictory, you can construct math nodes (or directly contruct the resulting hlist) in Lua but parsing and expanding macros is by definition using the TeX rather than Lua side of luatex unless you mean to write an alternative macro expansion language based on a parser written in Lua?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I see what you mean. What I mean by 'without tex' is 'without a .tex file containing the text'. I receive a string containing a TeX paragraph in lua (let's say through a socket). I would like to parse this string with TeX and return the node list.

Comment: oh just  `tex.sprint` the string back to be handled by TeX in that case. (but timing depends a bit on what else you are doing...)

Comment: Ah! That sounds like what I need. Thanks! Should I make `tex.sprint` print to a box that is not on the page and read the nodes from there? Would it be possible to get the nodes before line-breaking?

Comment: yes that's what I'd do, but you (may) need to print a second \directlua{} call to get control back to lua after you have written the box, you could write to an hbox to get pre-linebreaking or write to a vbox and use the pre_linebreak callback tio get control before the linebreaking pass

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to choose the 'output box' for `tex.sprint`, but I can't find how to do it. I'm new to lua and luatex, so I apologize if this is very basic.

Answer (score 2):

The following starts with a Lua string, typesets it in a box, uses the box (just so you can see it) then iterates over the nodes in the box giving their ID (as glyph/glue/math etc).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\directlua{\unexpanded{
function foo (n)
texio.write_nl("START")
local hnodes=tex.getbox(n).head
for n in node.traverse(hnodes) do
texio.write_nl("ID = " .. node.types()[(n.id or -1)] )
end
texio.write_nl("END")
end
tmpstr="A string with some $ \\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ maths
and a \\textbf{font} \\textit{change} or \\textsc{Two}."
tex.print("\\sbox0{" ..
tmpstr ..
"}")
tex.print("\\usebox{0}")
tex.print("\\directlua{foo(0)}")
}}
\end{document}
```

It produces a terminal output as below where the first two items are "glyph glue" corresponding to the staring text `A`

```
START
ID = glyph
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glue
ID = math
ID = hlist
ID = math
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = kern
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = kern
ID = glyph
ID = kern
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = kern
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = kern
ID = glue
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
ID = kern
ID = glyph
ID = glyph
END
```

Comment: Thanks so much for writing this demo! I see that the `tex.print("\\directlua{foo(0)}")` is required because `tex.print` is only executed/parsed after the lua code returns. Would you see a way around having to terminate the lua script? In my use case, the lua code never returns (listens to a socket), so the `sbox` and `foo` would never be executed.

Comment: Henri posted an answer here the other day using Lua co routines but I've not done that, I think I'll leave this answer as it is, but don't accept it, someone else may come up with a less intrusive technique, I'll see if I can find the link I am thinking of (or you could ask on luatex list the luatex developers are there not here)

Comment: see this and Hans's tugboat article (but I have not used that technique at all, so not sure if it will elp:-)  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470621/how-to-emulate-message-in-luatex/470667#470667