# How can I make macros called from tex.print tail-recursive?

Tags: luatex

Consider

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
%\usepackage{luacr}
%\usepackage{miscellaneous}
\begin{document}

\global\def\F{\directlua{f()}}
\begin{luacode*}
i=0
function f()
    if i<30 then
        i=i+1
        tex.sprint(i .. [[, \F]])
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\F

\end{document}
```

Problem:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
```

As far as I can see `tex.sprint` is "equivalent" to a `\input` that contains the printed content, and you can `\input` 15 levels at most.

Question:

- why does the *tail recursion elimination* does not work when the input is from a line instead of a token list?
- how to fix the issue? Assuming I need `tex.sprint()` e.g. to print some more string content to the right of `\F`.

<sub>in the meantime I find a workaround using `token.put_next()`, put a \relax and get it later.</sub>

Comment: for the background, I'm making some convenience wrapper to run TeX code from Lua using coroutine.

Comment: You're probably looking for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470667/10995

Comment: Tail call elimination obviously does not work because there is no `return`. Lua doesn't know that you are tail calling as part of `tex.sprint`.

Comment: This also sounds awfully like an [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean). What are you *actually* trying to do? There is probably a much simpler solution.

Comment: @HenriMenke I already explained above, didn't I?  "I'm making some convenience wrapper to run TeX code from Lua using coroutine" inspired from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/concurrently-interleaving-execution-of-lua-and-tex-in-luatex

Comment: Hm, on a second read, the answer there writes a loop in TeX... will think about it.

Comment: @HenriMenke What do you mean by "there's no `return`" here? if you mean Lua's`return` from `f()` function, it already returns normally by reaching the end of the function

Comment: To qualify for tail call elimination the function has to be of the form `function f() ... return f() end` which this one clearly isn't.

Comment: With XY problem I mean that to print a list of numbers you don't need a tail recursive hybrid Lua/TeX function, so the example is simplified a bit too much from what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @HenriMenke (anyway the closeinput one does work) --  No I'm talking about TeX tail call recursion (i.e. remove the input level when it's consumed), not Lua tail call recursion

Answer (score 4):

You can force tex to unwind the input stack before recursing by looking ahead with `\expandafter`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{luacr}
%\usepackage{miscellaneous}
\begin{document}

\def\F{\expanded{\noexpand\directlua{f()}\expandafter}}
\directlua{
i=0
function f()
    if i<30 then
        i=i+1
        tex.sprint(i .. [[, \string\F]])
    end
end
}
\F

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has the "side effect" of expanding whatever following \F though?

Answer (score 2):

#### 0. `texio.closeinput()`

<sub>Suggested by [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640922/how-can-i-make-macros-called-from-tex-print-tail-recursive?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1597381_640922)</sub>

Code:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\def\F{\directlua{f()}}
\begin{luacode*}
i=0
function f()
    if i~=0 then
        texio.closeinput()
    end
    if i<20000 then
        i=i+1
        tex.sprint(i .. [[, \F]])
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\F

\end{document}
```

The manual explains...

> This function that should be used with care. It acts as \endinput but at the Lua end. You can use it to (sort of) force a jump back to TeX.

which means that it drops the remaining content of the topmost "file".

Note/clarification of the manual,

- it doesn't *really* jump back to TeX, the following Lua content is still executed
- `tex.print()` commands preceding it is also dropped
- unlike `\endinput` the following content on the line is dropped
- **but** if there are some pending tokens put by `token.put_next()` they will be kept as long as those after it
- only apply to real "file"/pseudofile instead of e.g. argument token list

#### 1. Use token.put_next on the continuation token

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\def\F{\directlua{f()}}
\begin{luacode*}
i=0
function f()
    if i<20000 then
        i=i+1
        tex.sprint(i .. [[, ]])
        token.put_next(token.create("F"))
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\F

\end{document}
```

(experimentally, all `token.put_next()` comes after all `tex.*print()`, regardless of their order in the code)

I think that the reason this method works is that while expanding a macro, unlike when `token.get_next()` or `token.scan_toks()` etc. is executed, TeX unwinds the input stack (even in case the macro does not have any argument such as in this case)

#### 2. Use futurelet

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
%\usepackage{miscellaneous}
%\tracingmacros=1
\begin{document}

\def\F{\directlua{f()}}
\begin{luacode*}
i=0
function f()
    if i<20000 then
        i=i+1
        tex.sprint(i .. [[, \immediateassignment\futurelet\a\F]])
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\expanded{\F}
\end{document}
```

`\immediateassignment` used to make it work in expansion-only context.

Note that if the following token is a `notexpanded` token, it will be changed.

#### 3. (partially works only, do not use) Use token.put_next on another token and get_next it from inside Lua

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
%\usepackage{miscellaneous}
%\tracingmacros=1
\begin{document}

\def\F{\directlua{f()}}
\begin{luacode*}
i=0
function f()
    token.get_next()  -- the relax token, either the original one or result of put_next
    if i<3000 then
        i=i+1
        tex.sprint(i .. [[, \F]])
        token.put_next(token.create("relax"))
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\F\relax
\end{document}
```

This does not do proper tail-recursive (somehow `token.get_next()` does not eliminate the input level if it's exhausted),
so if 3000 is increased to a larger value you'll see

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```