# Throwing warnings inside \directlua

Tags: luatex, expl3, directlua

I'm trying to issue TeX warnings from within `\directlua` with accurate line numbers (pointing to the offending line in the `.tex` document).

When I compile the MWE below with lualatex, `\TestTex` issues a warning that correctly points to line 40. However, `\TestLua` and `\TestLuaIndirect` both issue warnings pointomg to line 1.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn { test } { test-warning } { #1 ~ \msg_line_context: }

\NewDocumentCommand { \TestTex } { }
  {
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \msg_warning:nnn { test } { test-warning } { tex ~ warning }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \TestLua } { }
  {
    \directlua
      {
        tex.sprint('\\ExplSyntaxOn'
            .. '\\msg_warning:nnn { test } { test-warning }'
            .. '{ lua ~ warning }'
            .. '\\ExplSyntaxOff')
      }
  }
  
\NewDocumentCommand { \TestLuaIndirect } { }
  {
    \directlua
      {
        tex.sprint('\\TestTex')
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test.

\TestTex

\TestLua

\TestLuaIndirect
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use (from Lua) something like `luatexbase.module_warning(module_name, message)` instead.

Comment: @MaxChernoff I was completely unaware of this method, but it's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicaislly `sprint` creates a new "file-like layer" in the input stack (imagine that a `\input{tmpfile}` is executed, and the warning itself is on line 1 of the temporary file). You want to unroll it "as if it's executed from a macro".

Speaking of which, `\ExplSyntaxOn` inside any `{...}` is almost-always wrong: [macros - Why doesn't \makeatletter work inside \newcommand? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201348/why-doesnt-makeatletter-work-inside-newcommand)

One possible workaround follows, use `\futurelet` to force unroll the input stack, similar to the case in my question/answer [luatex - How can I make macros called from tex.print tail-recursive? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640922/how-can-i-make-macros-called-from-tex-print-tail-recursive). Note that the `sprint` must be the **last** one in the `\directlua` block for this to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn { test } { test-warning } { #1 ~ \msg_line_context: }

\NewDocumentCommand { \TestTex } { }
  {
    \msg_warning:nnn { test } { test-warning } { tex ~ warning }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \TestLua } { }
  {
    \directlua
      {
        tex.sprint('\\ExplSyntaxOn\\def\\tmp{'
            .. '\\msg_warning:nnn { test } { test-warning }'
            .. '{ lua ~ warning }'
          .. '}\\ExplSyntaxOff\\futurelet\\tmpa\\tmp')
      }
  }
  
\NewDocumentCommand { \TestLuaIndirect } { }
  {
    \directlua
      {
        tex.sprint('\\futurelet\\tmpa\\TestTex')
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test.

\TestTex

\TestLua

\TestLuaIndirect
    
\end{document}
```

Of course the disadvantage is that the catcode is fixed.

An alternative is to print a token directly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn { test } { test-warning } { #1 ~ \msg_line_context: }

\NewDocumentCommand { \TestTex } { }
  {
    \msg_warning:nnn { test } { test-warning } { tex ~ warning }
  }
  
\NewDocumentCommand { \TestLuaIndirect } { }
  {
    \directlua
      {
        token.put_next(token.create('TestTex'))
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test.

\TestTex

\TestLuaIndirect
    
\end{document}
```

Refer to [Can the Lua part of LuaTeX know about tokens?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45293/can-the-lua-part-of-luatex-know-about-tokens?noredirect=1&lq=1) and `texdoc luatex` for some documentation.

Comment: This is fantastic information, thank you! One additional question though: how could I pass arguments to `\TestTex` inside `\TestLuaIndirect` in the second approach without leaving Lua? (For example, a warning message containing a few local Lua variables.)

Comment: @steve What do you mean? You _already_ leave Lua by executing some TeX code. (although the last link is basically all you have to work with in Lua.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `token.put_next(...)` exits Lua, that answers the question though (meaning it's not possible).